# In a C# .NET web application, can I download an Amazon S3 object directly into memory and serve it as an image?

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-s3

With the AWS .NET SDK, can I download an S3 Object (a .jpg image file) directly into memory? I'm sure I saw a solution to this floating around a few months ago, but can't find it now.

Assuming I can download the file directly into memory, can I then serve the image to the client using a

```
context.Response.Write(memoryStream object);
```

Thanks for your help. I know you're probably thinking, why would you do this? Why not just link to the file directly? It's a complex reason, I'm just trying to keep it simple for the time being. Cheers!

Comment: I'm not sure if this answers your question, but I'm creating the files, so I own them. Thanks!

Comment: If you're using the AWS .net SDK, here is someone that had the same issue as you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455454/retrieve-binary-data-from-s3-storage-through-aws-net-in-c-sharp

Comment: Thanks- that's exactly what I was looking for. I'm curious @Randolpho, do you think using the .NET SDK is any faster than just a standard HttpWebRequest?

Comment: @Hairgami_Master faster? No, they'll be about the same. The SDK will just abstract out building the URL and fetching the data for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can certainly get data from another source and load it into memory, but you have to fetch the data somehow.

Most likely that will be in the form of a web fetch. You could very easily go get the data using an [`HttpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) to the URL of the S3 object, read the data into a memory stream, and then write the data into your response stream. I would recommend you skip the memory stream step and do a buffered read from your S3 fetch response and write to your ASP.NET response.

There are caveats to this approach. First, you'll have to solve security if your S3 object isn't publicly accessible. Second, your initial ASP.NET request will pause while you are fetching this data, which will increase the latency for getting the image to the browser that could easily be fixed by simply linking to the object.

For example:

```
// Assuming url is the  url to the S3 object.
var buffer = new byte[1024*8]; // 8k buffer. 
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
var response = request.GetResponse();
int bytesRead = 0;
using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
{
    while((bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
    {
         Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Randolpho- I own the images and can make them public. Do you think this method is any faster/slower than using the AWS .NET API? Cheers.

Comment: In terms of raw speed, pulling the object via the AWS SDK will be about the same as the method I mention. In fact, given the scenario you've listed, you'll use most of the code above -- the only thing you'll replace are the lines `var request = ...` and `var response = ...`. If speed is your big worry, find a way to make the images public and link to them in your HTML. I know you've already said you can't do that, but that's about the only way to make it faster.

Comment: Thanks again @Randolpho. I ended up using your example. I was trying to get the AWS .NET wrapper to work, but for some reason I couldn't. Cheers!