# How to download file from amazon s3 using only c#(Without using AWS SDK)

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

My requirement is download a files from Amazon s3 with out using Aws sdk for C# and using restfull(HttpWebRequest & HttpWebResponse) api calls.

I got response after successfully uploaded the files into amazon s3. In that response having location,date,success code etc.So What I need to pass to get the file with get request

Comment: You can use the s3 URL of the file in HttpWebRequest to get the file contents. The s3 bucket needs to be publicly available for this to work. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081535/in-a-c-sharp-net-web-application-can-i-download-an-amazon-s3-object-directly-i)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In a C# .NET web application, can I download an Amazon S3 object directly into memory and serve it as an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081535/in-a-c-sharp-net-web-application-can-i-download-an-amazon-s3-object-directly-i)

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya ASW SDK provide Bucket class to pass path,folder & file name.Can we pass same in s3 URL in HttpWebRequest

Comment: You need to generate the complete URL of file which includes bucketname, folder path and filename with extension... and use that URL in WebRequest to download the file.

Answer (score -1):

Can't understand why you wouldn't want to use the SDK, but if that really is a requirement, the entire SDK is open-sourced on github and you could extract the relevant tidbits of the code from there, and incorporate directly into your application - so you wouldn't be using the SDK per se, just using a very small subset of the same code directly from the SDK.

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net

Comment: @user3209860 403 is permission error, check the iam user/role you're using has s3 access or the bucket policy isn't denying access.